# Assign unique ID based on two columns

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have a dataframe (df) that looks like this:

```
School Student  Year  
A         10    1999
A         10    2000
A         20    1999
A         20    2000
A         20    2001
B         10    1999
B         10    2000
```

And I would like to create a person `ID` column so that df looks like this:

```
ID School Student  Year  
1   A         10    1999
1   A         10    2000
2   A         20    1999
2   A         20    2000
2   A         20    2001
3   B         10    1999
3   B         10    2000
```

In other words, the `ID` variable indicates which person it is in the dataset, accounting for both Student number and School membership (here we have 3 students total).

I did `df$ID <- df$Student` and tried to request the value +1 if `c("School", "Student)` was unique. It isn't working. Help appreciated.

Comment: `as.numeric(factor(paste0(df$School, df$Student)))`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

We can do this in `base R` without doing any group by operation

```
df$ID <- cumsum(!duplicated(df[1:2]))
df
#   School Student Year ID
#1      A      10 1999  1
#2      A      10 2000  1
#3      A      20 1999  2
#4      A      20 2000  2
#5      A      20 2001  2
#6      B      10 1999  3
#7      B      10 2000  3
```

NOTE: Assuming that 'School' and 'Student' are ordered

---

Or using `tidyverse`

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
    mutate(ID = group_indices_(df, .dots=c("School", "Student"))) 
#  School Student Year ID
#1      A      10 1999  1
#2      A      10 2000  1
#3      A      20 1999  2
#4      A      20 2000  2
#5      A      20 2001  2
#6      B      10 1999  3
#7      B      10 2000  3
```

As @radek mentioned, in the recent version (`dplyr_0.8.0`), we get the notification that `group_indices_` is deprecated, instead use `group_indices`

```
df %>% 
   mutate(ID = group_indices(., School, Student))
```

Comment: I did the first one but had to write it as cumsum(!duplicated(df$1,df$2)) to get it to work. Thanks!

Comment: @Quixotic  The `duplicated` works on a vector or data.frame/matrix, but if you use two vectors as arguments, it may not work

Comment: `group_indices_()` is deprecated. Should be now `mutate(ID = group_indices(df, School, Student))`?

Answer (score 12):

Group by School and Student, then assign group id to `ID` variable.

```
library('data.table')
df[, ID := .GRP, by = .(School, Student)]

#    School Student Year ID
# 1:      A      10 1999  1
# 2:      A      10 2000  1
# 3:      A      20 1999  2
# 4:      A      20 2000  2
# 5:      A      20 2001  2
# 6:      B      10 1999  3
# 7:      B      10 2000  3
```

**Data:**

```
df <- fread('School Student  Year  
A         10    1999
      A         10    2000
      A         20    1999
      A         20    2000
      A         20    2001
      B         10    1999
      B         10    2000')
```