# R - Create ID by multiple factors

Tags: r, dataframe, label, factors

How do I create a new ID label summarizing the information stored in two factors. I would like the one factor to be *nested (!?)* within the other one.

As a small example: Let's say I surveyed many trees and now I want to add a label to each examined branch that gives me the number of the tree and the number of the branch *on that* tree. It would be unnecessary and confusing, if all branches had just an ongoing ID.

#### Example code:

```
mydata = data.frame(tree   = rep(letters[1:3], each = 20),
                    branch = rep(round(runif(12)*1000, 0), each = 5),
                    values = runif(60))
```

*(Please don't ask me, why the branches have such strange numbers, this is just an example!)*

Of course, I could just use `interaction(mydata$treat, mydata$labels)` like [this answer](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-November/178808.html) suggests. Also, for a unique ID I could use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921674/assign-unique-id-based-on-two-columns). But both would give me an ongoing ID which is not discriminating between trees! I could also use a long and complicated `for` loop, but I'd like to have a simple answer (since I expect there to be one...).

#### Expected Output:

Should look something like the new ID column in the end.

```
mydata = data.frame(tree   = rep(letters[1:3],each = 20),
                    branch = rep(round(runif(12)*1000, 0), each = 5),
                    values = runif(60),
                    ID     = rep(rep(1:4, each = 5)));mydata

mydata$ID = interaction(mydata$tree, mydata$ID)
```

### EDIT:

So the solution in the comments by @suchait <s>works well for the example data</s> actually gives me an ongoing ID not discriminating between trees. Also, I have no knowledge of the `data.table` package and I cannot get my head around how it works in detail. When I apply the solution to my `tibble`, it won't work (it gives me again an ongoing ID ignoring one factor). Therefore, I would really like to see a `dplyr` solution or something similar.

Comment: `library(data.table)
setDT(mydata)
mydata[, ID := .GRP, by = c("tree", "branch")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A dplyr solution using `group_by` to group the branches from each tree separately then just converting the branch IDs to factors and using the factor number as the branch ID

```
library(tidyverse)

tmp <- mydata %>% 
  group_by(tree) %>% 
  mutate(ID = str_c(tree, as.numeric(as.factor(branch)), sep = "."))
```

Comment: Nice, now I understand why I had problems with my actual `data.frame`. The  `branch` column was of type `factor` not `character`. Changing that, it now works well for me. Thank you!