# Assign unique ID's based on four columns and across two data frames in r

Tags: r, dataframe, data-cleaning

I want to assign the same unique ID's to competitors in both of the below data frames (master.treeDQ2 and rank_table).

The master.treeDQ2 data frame has two competitor names in each row, while rank_table only has one in each row.

I would like to assign a unique ID to each competitor **based on their name and the gym they train at**. This is to avoid assigning the same ID to different people with the same name.

In the master.treeDQ2 df, some people in the comp_01name column also appear in the comp_02name column, while others only appear in one or the other.

#### **I would like R to do the following:**

- give the same ID's to people that appear in both comp_01name and comp_02name.
- assign ID's in comp_02name not already used in comp_01name.
- assign the same ID's used for each competitor in master.treeDQ2 to the corresponding competitor in rank_table.

**Is there maybe a loop or a function I can apply to get this done?**

I saw something similar to what I need [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42921674/assign-unique-id-based-on-two-columns), but it only works with two columns. So I'm stuck at only having unique ID's for competitor 1.

What I have:

```
rank_table = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/rank_table_complete2.csv')

master.treeDQ2 = read.csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bandcar/Examples/main/master.treeDQ.edited_draft6.csv')

# ASSIGN ID'S by name

# competitor 1
master.treeDQ2$ID1 <- cumsum(!duplicated(master.treeDQ2[,c(11,12)]))
```

Simplified version of what I want to achieve for the master data frame:

```
comp01 gym1 ID1    comp02 gym2 ID2 
A      w      1    D      z      4
A      w      1    D      z      4
B      x      2    A      w      1
B      x      2    D      z      4
B      x      2    D      z      4
C      y      3    A      w      1
C      y      3    B      x      2
```

Simplified version of what I want to achieve in rank_table:

```
competitor ID
C          3
D          4 
D          4     
A          1
B          2
B          2
```

Comment: `df[,c('ID1','ID2')] <- as.integer(factor(unlist(df[, c(11,12)])))`

Comment: It didn't keep the same unique ID's for people who appeared in both columns. I noticed you only referenced columns 11 and 12. Those are the columns for competitor 1 and competitor 1 gym. Column 16 and 17 are the columns for competitor 2 and their gym. Is there any way to adjust what you have so that all four columns are considered when assigning unique ID's? I tried adding 16 and 17 to the list with 11 and 12, but it still didn't give the correct ID's

Comment: I just coppied your code whereby you had 11 and 12. just put all the columns that you want to have the same ID inside the `c(..)` and run the same code as I gave. You are not interested in the gym but rather in the competitor. Only include the columns with competitor and not gym\